# Can't add event/task quick action to managed package

Tags: managed-package, lightning-quickaction

We would like to include in our managed package an event quick action that maps to a lightning component. However, from the package > add components page such action doesn't not appear.

We have previously added lightning component quick actions for objects like Account, Contact and Lead without any problem. Even now I can create a quick action for such objects and it immediately becomes visible for addition int the managed package > components > add > action view.

Why are event / task quick actions not visible for addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an Event Action Lightning Component to my managed package by including it in an Event Layout that's included in the package.

Also as mentioned, "If you plan on packaging a Lightning component action, the component the action invokes must be marked as access=global."

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_component_actions.htm

*** I just tried without the "access=global" and it seems to work. May not be needed. ***

Comment: It actually worked but I wonder why I don't have to apply this trick for the other objects (Account, Contact, Lead). I have added no specific layout for them and yet the actions are in the package.